# Entity framework scaffolding is changing title of dbset entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity called "links" in the database in my. Net core project, but after I perform scaffolding the generator causes the change and overwrite this entity to "linksu" . Has anyone met with this problem?

Comment: Maybe a problem with [the pluralization service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-turn-pluralization-on-and-off-o-r-designer?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems it is working now properly. Thank you a lot! :)